# Are there constants for each part of the date in TDate for Delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-12-athens

I found that you can use the following code to create a `TTime` with the time you're entering:

```
const MyTime: TTime = (12 * OneHour)   + (15 * OneMinute) 
                      + (33 * OneSecond) + (123 * OneMillisecond);
```

The constants `OneHour`, `OneMinute`, `OneSecond` and `OneMillisecond` work perfectly for this use case.

When I do `ShowMessage(TimeToStr(MyTime));` then I get exactly what I wanted.

Is there something like this for `TDate` that would allow me to create a constant `TDate` like I do with `TTime`? Are there constants for each part of `TDate`?

Comment: EncodeDateTime, EncodeDate, EncodeTime. Generally, there are many nice functions in the DateUtils unit.

Comment: `OneDay` = 1, but what about `OneMonth`? Should it be 28, 29, 30, 31, some average? And `OneYear`? 365? 366? 365.24? Clearly it is impossible to define such constants in the way you expect.